# Нужна ли запятая перед "согласно"?

Tags: пунктуация

Список сотрудников с закрепляемыми за ними абонентскими номерами, а так же предельные размеры расходов на «сотовую» связь согласно  списку.

Comment: «Сотовая» — что не так с этим словом, зачем кавычки?

Answer (score 3):

Список сотрудников с закрепляемыми за ними абонентскими номерами, а также предельные размеры расходов на «сотовую» связь **согласно списку**.

**Оборот не обособляется**, что связано с его нераспространенностью, расположением в конце предложения, деловым стилем речи и отсутствием паузы.

Comment: <Большое спасибо!